# Passing variables to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function

I have the following function

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function showUser(test, order) 
{ 
const but = document.getElementById(test);
if(but.getAttribute("onClick") === `showUser('${test}','DESC')`)
{
    but.setAttribute("onClick",`showUser('${test}','ASC')`);
}
else
{
    but.setAttribute("onClick",`showUser('${test}','DESC')`);
}

var users = document.getElementById('instructor-filter').value;
var club = document.getElementById('club-filter').value
var sort = test;
var order = order;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}    

xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxcall.php?student_instructor="+users+"&club="+club+"&sortby="+sort+"&orderby="+order,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

And I call this function in two places of my code like so

```
<select id="instructor-filter" onChange="showUser()">
```

and

```
<div class="col-sm-2"><a id="student_forename" onClick="showUser('student_forename','ASC')">Forename</a></div>
```

One call doesn't require any variables to be passed to the function, the other one does require two variables to be passed to it.

This is causing issues where by the one I call which doesn't pass any variables no longer works but the other does.

Because I have set two variables in the function does this mean every time I use the function I have to supply two values?

Comment: `// code for IE6, IE5` Unless you work for a company that insists on living in the dark ages, you should delete this code. If you _do_ work for such a company you should start a job search immediately. If you're in a position to require modern browsers, you should look into using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead of XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: :) hi stephen, good point! it's a snippet of code i found online and being as i don't know much about JS i didn't want to edit it as it was working. I'll remove it now its been pointed out :) thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you dont pass any values, by default it will take as undefined.
You may need to set some default values inside the function for the variables to make it work.

Comment: thank you for your reply, that explains why it isn't working. I'll look at trying to solve this by adding default values into the function tho my javascript knowledge is pretty poor to be honest.